# Azure CloudApp - How to properly set CNAME DNS (NGINX)

Tags: azure, nginx, dns, azure-virtual-network

First time i'm using azure and i am having a lot of trouble connecting my domain at godaddy to my server.

In Azure portal , i set up a dns name label :

```
yyy.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
```

Then in godaddy portal :

[image: DNS]

NGINX Settings :

```
server {
    server_name .azure.com; 
    return 301 http://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {

    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    listen 10.0.1.4;
    root /home/domain/public_html/public;
    index index.html index.php;
    fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
```

Issues i'm having :

1)

site works (www.example.com)

Site does not work(example.com)

2)

I don't want the default azure url to work (yyy.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com)

I want to redirect all occurrence to example.com

3)

Mail is not working

p.s : I'm using Virtualmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> site works (www.example.com)
>
> Site does not work(example.com)

If you want `www.example.con` and `example.com` work together, we should add **two DNS records**, one is `www` and one is `@`.

Like this:

```
Type        Hostname        Value    
CNAME        www              xxx.cloudapp.azure.com
CNAME        @                xxx.cloudapp.azure.com
```

> I don't want the default azure url to work
>   (yyy.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com)
>
> I want to redirect all occurrence to example.com

If you don't want use Azure url, we can disable Azure VM's DNS settings, add **A record** to godaddy(use Azure VM's public IP address).

> Mail is not working

Please try to use A record then set MX record test it again.